# Freeze rain drop effect LED (CD 4017 IC)

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

The above is a CD 4017 rain LED chip which lights up one LED consecutively, one after another.

The LED at pin 7 can be frozen by attaching the clock_inhibit pin to pin 7, I would like to freeze the LED at pin 7 by disabling or grounding the clock signal so that there is no clock signal which means it will freeze. How do I accomplish this using transistors as a switch?

LTspice file is on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10n7uCL4mRT3-Llu2Hf0W83psMjpMYJzO?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: So stop the clock when correct LED is lighted up to stop further counting?

Comment: @Justme, ah yes, that;s smart, how do I do it :) ?

Comment: @Justme, my guess would be you have to build another circuit which when given an input pulse, it gives a (Logic 1 forever until it is reset) reading which then cuts off the clock right :) ?

Comment: The [CD4017 is a decade counter,](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd4017b) not a dedicated "rain drop effect LED" IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a diode and resistor is possibly the simplest way of disabling CD4017's clk input to freeze at a particular count value.
When the selected output pin goes active high, the diode pulls up the clk line toward Vdd, and doesn't allow the clk to pull toward GND because of series resistance R12.
Will this work when you drive LEDS rather than 10k resistors? Perhaps not as well.

This only works because CD4017 clk input is a *schmitt* type buffered input where noise is reduced. Logic levels are compromised with this diode clamp - but it seems to work in LTspice.
[image: raindrop cd4017 ltspice schematic]

Comment: Hi thank you, works like a charm on my breadboard. May I ask one last question, this IC, CD 4017 can handle a 5MHz clock signal in datasheet, will the diode somehow reduce the MHz clock frequency by a lot or it wont really affect :) ?

Comment: Jessica, yes, you've pointed out another problem - upper clock frequency will be limited with this circuit. Reason?...with R12, clk driving impedance is very much higher so that circuit capacitance limits rise and fall time.

Comment: oh dear, I mean just curious, how would you solve this issue then haha :) ?

Comment: Jessica, I would regard this idea as a "kludge" because logic levels and rise/fall times are compromised. It might be acceptable for the low-frequency "raindrop" application, but I'd hesitate to use it where speeds are high, and where reliable operation is mandatory. The solution in this case would use an additional **OR gate** logic chip.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying again :). About the OR gate, how would you place it, do you mind simulating it in LT Spice using OR gate, I am curious to know haha :)

Comment: Jessica, kudos to you for breadboarding this - that's a considerable effort. Please, please extend your effort by doing *logic design*...this is an excellent learning experience. I've suggested that an OR gate can duplicate this diode-resistor kludge. Doing this kind of logic reduction is a basic skill that *every* digital designer develops.

Comment: Hi, to implement your OR gate, does the diode still included?

Comment: Hi, I updated a new post above. I assume that when R7reads 0V, the output would be 1 and 0 so that it excluded the resistor and diode. When R7 read 4V, the output will be the 0 and 1 so that it include the resistor and diode to function as a freezer? Is that right ? :)

Comment: Jessica, you've introduced another *different* method to disable the clocking source (with voltage-controlled switch) that is so far incomplete. Using a SW is OK, and can avoid trouble at high frequencies. Only one SW is needed, with the addition of a pull-up or pull-down resistor to ensure that the CD4017 clk input doesn't "float".

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. At the correct moment, stop the clock or inhibit all chips from counting. Internally the inhibit will just make the chip ignore clock.

You can build a logic circuit to stop the clock by keeping it asserted when the selected counter output becomes asserted.

You can also build a logic ciruit to assert the count inhibit for all chips when the selected counter output becomes asserted.

Comment: Hi, so I have actually built this circuit in real life, but I use 2 CD4017 counters and it works perfectly with led on and off consecutively one after another. So, in order to freeze the led at a specific location, lets say the 14th led, I attach 2 wire from the 14th led to the clock inhibit for both chips, and try reset everything to count it again, but the led does not freeze tho :)

Comment: Hi, do you mind showing me how it is done to ground the clock signal in order to freeze the pin 7 led ? I have updated my question which include LT Spice file to download :)